Cookie http-only is not stored on browswer when it's received as a set-cookie header from the backend (Backend: Symfony, Frontend: NextJS)
I have two projects, both of them using Docker in local environment: frontend is https://domain.test:3000 and backend is https://domain.test(:443)
Backend has an API made with ApiPlatform, Lexik JWT and NelmioCors: everything is working and the /api/authentication returns 200 and sets and http-only cookie in the server.
When frontend tries to access to this endpoint, everything's fine and it receives the header set-cookie with JWTToken=xxxxx
I don't receive any message about cors problem, everything works fine and I get a 200 response in the frontend.
But browser doesn't store the cookie.
If I try the endpoint in the swagger page of ApiPlatform, works fine and the cookie is stored.
In NextJS I have written { withCredentials: true }, and I can see the logs in the backend with the access:
async function login() {
    console.log('Login');
    const email = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_EMAIL;
    const password = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_PASSWORD;
    await apiClient.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/authentication`, {
        email: email,
        password: password,
    });
}

Here you receive set-cookie header:
apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        console.log('Interceptor for response successful in ' + response.headers["set-cookie"]);
        return response;
    },........

NextJs access to the endpoint on the url https://container_service_name because I can't use there the domain name.
What am I forgetting?

You mentioned that the NextJs accesses the endpoint via backend access, meaning the API response never reached the browser, right? Would that probably be why you can't see the cookie in the browser?

Hmmm... I think I am not familiar enough with NextJS, but I created a TSX file with the logic to connect to the API (login(), get() and getCollection() functions using Axios) and then I created a page.tsx for product-list, and in this page I call the login()+getCollection() functions to receive an array with all the products. I thought doing things in this way API call reaches the browser, isn't it?
